# Как объявить блок памяти, допускающий запись только словами 32 бита

Tags: c++, c

Пишется программа на C. В пространстве памяти есть области, допускающие запись только сразу 32 бита. То есть записывать по 8 или по 16 битов в нее нельзя, это приведет к исключению "Ошибка доступа к шине". Как наиболее безопасно описать это на C? Другими словами, как объяснить компилятору, что писать можно только словами по 32 бита, и адрес обязательно выравнивается по границе 32 бита?

Comment: вряд ли так просто заставите компилятор это все проверить. Добавьте сами проверку. Это же просто. А вот писать только по 32бита сразу - думаю, лучше написать ассемблерную вставку, которая все сделает правильно.

Comment: Смотрите в специфические платформо-зависимые настройки для вашего компилятора. С точки зрения стандарта, гранулярность записи не определена.

Comment: Скорее нужен свой менеджер памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, абсолютной гарантии вам никто дать не может, это ж неуправляемые языки, кто угодно может получить адрес и сделать `reinterpret_cast`. Но бороться с злонамеренными программистами нет резона, если кто-то хочет сделать неправильно, он уж найдёт путь.

Поэтому проще всего просто объявить вашу память как массив 32-битных слов.

```
#include <cstdint>
std::int32_t* data;
```

или для C

```
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t* data;
```

Пользователь, который будет обращаться через `data[i]`, гарантированно ничего не сломает.

---

На C++ можно запрятать указатель внутрь класса с переопределённым оператором `[]`, чтобы удостовериться, что возможен только доступ по индексу, а не адресная арифметика. Это всё равно не спасает от `reinterpret_cast`, но наверное более чисто объясняет семантику вашей области памяти. Заодно и логику получения/освобождения этой памяти можно засунуть в конструктор и спрятать от чужих глаз.

---

Обновление: На современных версиях C++ есть [ключевое слово `alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), которое явно объявляет память с нужным выравниванием:

```
alignas(4) char cacheline[128];
```

(В C вам придётся, возможно, включить `<stdalign.h>` или воспользоваться `_Alignas`.)

В C++ есть также более высокоуровневая [структура `aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), которая по идее должна делать то, что вам нужно.

Скопирую пример с cppreference.com (для ваших целей его, очевидно, нужно будет подправить, чтобы выделял/использовал память там, где надо, а не на стеке):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    std::size_t m_size = 0;

public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
        new(data+m_size) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }

    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data+pos);
    }

    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data+pos)->~T();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_vector<std::uint32_t, 10> v;
    v.emplace_back(20);
    v.emplace_back(10);
    v.emplace_back(2015);
    std::cout << v[0] << '\n' << v[1] << '\n' << v[2] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее простой, понятный и безопасный метод - написать комментарий БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ "в этой области памяти все переменные должны быть 32-битными!" и неукоснительно ему следовать. Дальше компилятор сам справится.

На чистом си по-другому никак. Ну, можно все операции чтения-записи вести через специальные функции, но это очень криво будет.
Менеджер памяти тут никоим боком. Ну выделит он нужное количество байт в нужном месте, ну и что?
На C++ можно придумать какой-нибудь класс с переопределёнными операторами, и наследовать всё от него. Но тоже нетривиально как-то...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно этих 4-х функций Вам будет достаточно.

```
unsigned char
get_32b_char (void *addr)
{
  int32_t *p = (int *)((long)addr & ~0x3L), 
    ofs = (char *)addr - (char *)p, 
    v = *p;

  return ((char *)&v)[ofs];
}

unsigned short
get_32b_short (void *addr)
{
  unsigned short s;
  unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)&s;

  c[0] = get_32b_char(addr++);
  if (sizeof(short) != sizeof(char))
    c[1] = get_32b_char(addr);

  return s;
}

void
put_32b_char (void *addr, char c)
{
  int32_t *p = (int *)((long)addr & ~0x3L), 
    ofs = (char *)addr - (char *)p, 
    v = *p;
  char *a = (char *)&v;
  a[ofs] = c;
  *p = v;
}


void
put_32b_short (void *addr, short s)
{
  char *pc = (char *)&s;

  put_32b_char(addr++, pc[0]);
  if (sizeof(short) != sizeof(char))
    put_32b_char(addr, pc[1]);
}
```

Обратите внимание, функции для short позволяют работать с невыровненной (для short) памятью, в т.ч. для полей пересекающих границу 32-бит слова.
Думаю, если аналогичная функциональность понадобится для других (32 и 64-бит) типов данных, то Вы сможете написать ее самостоятельно.

**Внимание!**
Если речь идет о регистрах какого-либо устройства на IO шине, то реализация short может быть некорректной, поскольку доступ будет проходить не за одно, а за два обращения, что в некоторых случаях может быть недопустимо (устройство будет работать не так, как вы ожидали). Естественно, для таких случаев пересечение short-ом границы 32-бит слова тоже недопустимо и функции с short надо очевидным образом (вставляем байты в локальную переменную int32_t и записываем ее обратно за один раз) изменить.
(хотя, подобные ограничения лучше сразу оговаривать в вопросе).

Удачи.